# Export to CSV separating all chars into fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I'm having a little trouble with a python script that I'm writing to audit all the CSV files from my firm's many disparate applications, and I have it nearly done with a proof of concept to bring to the boss, AND show off what I can do with python, but the issue is that I don't understand the CSV class in python all that well....

Here is an example of what my list of computer information looks like:

```
['EB-ABORTZ,True,False,False,0', 'EB-AGONCHAROVA,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-AHART-1,True,False,False,0', 'EB-AHEIDENREICH,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-ALOCKLEAR,True,False,False,0', 'EB-AMARGULIS,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-ASKLAR,True,False,False,0', 'EB-ASKLAR-1,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-ASKLAR-3,True,False,False,0', 'EB-BCHOW-1,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-BJOHNSON,True,False,False,0', 'EB-BLYLE,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-BRUSSUM,True,False,False,0', 'EB-CCLEARY,True,False,False,0',
 'EB-...]
```

and here is an example of what the code at the end produces.....

```
"E","B","-","A","B","O","R","T","Z",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
"E","B","-","A","G","O","N","C","H","A","R","O","V","A",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
"E","B","-","A","H","A","R","T","-","1",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
"E","B","-","A","H","E","I","D","E","N","R","E","I","C","H",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
"E","B","-","A","L","O","C","K","L","E","A","R",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
"E","B","-","A","M","A","R","G","U","L","I","S",",","T","r","u","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","F","a","l","s","e",",","0"
```

Here is a copy of the method I've used to try to export the data to a CSV format after the fact.

```
def collate_computers(computers):
    with open('results.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', )as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=',')
        for c in computers:
            writer.writerow(c)
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly? I can use your code correctly. What is your EXPECTED output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV writer function, `writerow`, takes a list as the input and writes each element to the row. When you pass a single string into the function, the writer interprets the string as a list of characters.

I am assuming that you want to write each row as is appears in the string. So instead of using `writer.writerow(c)`, use `writer.writerow(c.split(','))`. This splits the string into a list where it is seperated by a comma.

Your csv file should then look like this:

```
EB-ABORTZ,True,False,False,0
EB-AGONCHAROVA,True,False,False,0
EB-AHART-1,True,False,False,0
EB-AHEIDENREICH,True,False,False,0
EB-ALOCKLEAR,True,False,False,0
EB-AMARGULIS,True,False,False,0
EB-ASKLAR,True,False,False,0
EB-ASKLAR-1,True,False,False,0
EB-ASKLAR-3,True,False,False,0
EB-BCHOW-1,True,False,False,0
EB-BJOHNSON,True,False,False,0
EB-BLYLE,True,False,False,0
EB-BRUSSUM,True,False,False,0
EB-CCLEARY,True,False,False,0
```

Answer (score 0):

as is, your write rows method is generated comma separated values (.csv)

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,
>   but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL
>   characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the
>   encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like
>   UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.
>   further information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

if you would like 1 string per row (that is 1 list item per row)

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    for c in computers:
        csvWriter.writerow([c.encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each item in `computers` is a string, and strings in Python are sequences of characters, so `writer.writerow()` thinks each character is a separate field. To fix that you need to first `split` each string into fields based on where the commas are in it:

```
import csv

def collate_computers(computers):
    with open('results.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=',')
        for s in computers:
            fields = s.split(',')
            writer.writerow(fields)

computers = [
    "EB-ABORTZ,True,False,False,0",
    "EB-AGONCHAROVA,True,False,False,0",
    "EB-AHART-1,True,False,False,0",
    "EB-AHEIDENREICH,True,False,False,0",
    "EB-ALOCKLEAR,True,False,False,0",
    "EB-AMARGULIS,True,False,False,0"
]

collate_computers(computers)
```

**`results.csv`**

```
"EB-ABORTZ","True","False","False","0"
"EB-AGONCHAROVA","True","False","False","0"
"EB-AHART-1","True","False","False","0"
"EB-AHEIDENREICH","True","False","False","0"
"EB-ALOCKLEAR","True","False","False","0"
"EB-AMARGULIS","True","False","False","0"
```